# MSAccess: Selecting one row out of a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ms-access, select, ms-access-2010

In MS Access 2010, I have TableA related one-to-many to TableB, and TableB related one-to-many to TableC. TableC has one numeric field and one date field (in addition to the lookup field).

FormA's datasource is a select query that joins TableA and TableB. I want to add one additional read-only field to FormA that contains the numeric field from TableC from the row with the most recent date.

What's the best way to go about doing this? Should I create a field in TableB and create an update query (or macro?) that populates that column prior to the join query running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a form and you require read only, so DlookUp should suit : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786

```
= DLookup("[numeric field]", "TableC", "[LookupKey] = " & [PK] & " AND TheDate = DMax(""TheDate"", ""TableC"", ""LookupKey=" & [PK] & """)")
```

There are two problems with the edit by the OP, the first is that it suggests that `date`is an acceptable field name, it is a reserved word and should not be used. Secondly, it suggests that square brackets are needed in DlookUp, they are not.

Alternatively:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

s = "SELECT TOP 1 c.[numeric field] " _
  & "FROM TableC c " _
  & "WHERE c.LookupKey= " & Me.[PK]
  & "ORDER BY c.TheDate DESC"

set rs = currentDB.Openrecordset(s)
Me.SomeControl = rs![numeric field]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not clear how to select the numeric field corresponding to the most recent date using this method, however. Right now I have

`=DLookUp("[numeric field]", "TableC", "[TableC]![LookupKey] = " & [PK])`

which returns multiple values. How do I limit the results based on another field (the date) in TableC?

Comment: You can combine it with a DMax (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/dmin-dmax-functions-HA001228826.aspx)

Comment: @ZachB You really, really should not use reserved words in such as `date`for field or control names, in fact, of all the reserved words you could use in MS Access, 'date' may be the worst, hence my use of TheDate as the field name. I would not wish to encourage anyone to think that 'date' is acceptable.

Comment: Please note that that's **not** what the above line originally read. Your original line was actually stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/204654). The purpose of my edits was to (1) add hashes (#) around DMax, (2) add the AND in the criteria field, and (3) take DMax out of the quotes and fix the escaped quotes accordingly. Brackets are required if your field names have spaces or other special chars. Good point about reserve words. While that wasn't my real field name, good to not be confusing.

Comment: Taking DMax out of the quotes means that you will have to format the date returned. While DMax is within the quotes, you do not need hashes. I may have had some errors, but your changes are not improvements.